# Translation Golf XXVIII - An anniversary of a song alone

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

Oh, let the organ roll, let the church bell ring.

Cause @walen this game is going to win!

---

En esta ocasión propongo volver a la rima, con el bonus que esta trae. La particularidad es que es una canción de [calipso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calipso_(m%C3%BAsica)), cuya métrica de rima es A-A, B-B, C-C... Z-Z, es decir, cada rima dura 2 versos.

Aprovechando el aniversario de la fecha y los bombos de la realeza británica actual, decidí traer una canción llamada [*Edward the VIII*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-x1vRJ91AY), llamada en otras versiones como *Love alone*. Parte de su letra dice:

> It's love, love alone
> that cause King Edward to leave his throne
> (...)Oh, what a sad disappointment
> was endured by the British government
> On the tenth of December, we heard the talk
> that he gave the throne to the Duke of York
> (...)Oh, how Baldwin tried to break down his plan
> he said, Come what may the American
> And if I can't get a boat to set me free
> well, I will walk to Miss Simpson across the sea
> Scepter, robes and my crown is on my mind
> but I cannot leave Miss Simpson behind
> (...)And if you see Miss Simpson walk in the street
> she can fall an angel with her body beat
>
> <sub>448 Caracteres</sub>

La traducción propuesta viene con el bonus por rima asonante (5%), si se logra que la rima sea consonante, la reducción es del 10% de caracteres (se aproxima al número superior de caracteres)

> Por amor, solo fue por amor
> que el Rey Eduardo su trono dejó
> (...) Que triste desilusión
> la que gobierno británico sufrió
> El diez de diciembre mandó la razón
> que el reino quedaba para el Duque de York
> Y cuánto intentó Baldwin que en su plan cediese
> y al final dijo "cuánto puede la estadounidense"
> Y si no conseguimos un barco para irnos
> pues con la señorita Simpson tomamos el mar de camino
> Por mi mente me siguen joyas, cetro y corona
> pero a la señorita Simpson no la dejo sola
> (...) Es que si a la señorita Simpson la ven caminar
> desde el cielo hasta un ángel se podría lanzar
>
>  <sub>455 caracteres - 5% de rima asonante = 433 caracteres</sub>

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [Translation-Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf), our game-specific chat room, or in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### <s>246 (234) 170 (153) 184 (175) 150 (135) 119 (113) 107 (97) 97 (88) 87 (79) 85 (77)</s> 79 (72)

> 10/12.
> Stan sin goce:
> Ed a
> Wallis va.
> "De
> pie
> o a bote".
> Rote
> el Rey:
> de ley,
> al tato.
> "¿Boato?
> No: ella".
> ¡Yanqui bella!

14 versos consonantes aa bb cc dd ee ff gg.

Comment: recurso genial, digno de aplauso pero me temo que si te lo valgo el juego terminará siendo 2 versos que rimen... prefiero los 14 versos

Comment: [Yo después de ver la actualización](https://goo.gl/images/Ff8fMb).

Comment: Maldito walen, eso mismo pensé yo, como la estructura iba de dos en dos quitar algunos versos. Iba a preguntar en el chat si sería válido pero pensé mejor en guardarme ese as bajo la manga y hacer primero mi traducción. Llego tarde para eso aunque parece que @VeAqui no lo aceptará.

Comment: ¿No puedo votar otra vez? Me encanta esta versión menos lo de 10/12 que queda raro

Comment: @blonfu no veo por qué no iba a aceptarlo. A mí me ha parecido genial, de hecho respetando los 14 versos al final quedan versos tan cortos que el poema queda algo ridículo. Pero puedo insistir por esa vía, a ver qué queda...

Comment: @Charlie porque lo ha dicho él

Comment: pues @walen... el único pero en este instante es entre *amor / abdicó* como rima consonante (vaya que estoy peor que Baldwin...)

Comment: Merece que ganes este reto solo por la versión en rima consonante de 107 caracteres. A eso lo llamo yo una obra maestra del translation-golf.

Comment: ¿No haces alusión a Baldwin?

Answer (score 3):

## 123 caracteres

A la porra la rima...

> Colado,
>   Eduardo abdicó
>   en Jorge
>   un 10/12.
>   Lores
>   decepcionados
>   y boicot inútil
>   de Baldwin:
>   el rey se va
>   como sea
>   con la Simpson.
>   Su gracia
>   es más
>   que el trono.

Respuesta anterior:

## <strike>258</strike> 190 * 0,9 (rima consonante) = <strike>233</strike> 171 caracteres

> [Se coló](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9jtl8nd#404DBbN)
>   Eduardo, y abdicó.
>   ¡Qué susto,
>   Lord vetusto!
>   Mes doce, día diez:
>   Jorge [ha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jv4Frsm#M808CrT) la [vez](http://dle.rae.es/?id=biPx6YF).
>   Baldwin le quiso [chafar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8SjHCJI)
>   mas él no iba a parar:
>   "O a la Simpson en barco
>   o a pie [cruzo el charco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8cJKgH1).
>   ¿Corona, cetro y sayo?
>   ¡Por ella me desmayo!
>   Un [contoneo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AVv8yPv):
>   un ángel ateo."

Comment: @walen yo es que o hago rima consonante, o nada. :-D Pero reconozco que también he pensado que muchas veces lo mejor es sencillamente saltarse la rima, pues generalmente te obliga a meter más texto del necesario para poder mantenerla y en ocasiones no compensa.

Comment: @Charlie, casi me quito el sombrero... pero para el mundo hispano el rey inglés fue Eduardo VIII y no Edward VIII (cosas del idioma...)

Comment: (┛◉Д◉)┛彡┻━┻   jaja!

Comment: @walen no verses, no rhyme...

Comment: @walen [como desees](https://images.gr-assets.com/hostedimages/1420766716ra/13259321.gif).

Answer (score 3):

### 76 para la prosa, 194*90% = 175 para la rima

Prosa libre:

> 12.10:
> Edu amó,
> abdicó
> Jorge¹:
> ¡Acepto!²
> Stan³:
> ¡No!⁴
> "Sin
> bote,
> iré^5,
> ver a
> Yanqui-Bessie^6:
> pompis^7
> antes
> de
> todo"

1: Es un hecho conocido que la corona va al duque de York si ella no tiene hij@s. Es también un hecho conocido que él se llamaba George...

2: ...Si en ese contexto dice que acepta, es que acepta la corona.

3: Stanley Baldwin, Premier

4: "Oh, what a sad disappointment
was endured by the British government": si el Premier dice algo, tambien lo dice el govierno.

5:  En el sentido "andar".

6: Bessie era el nombre caído cariñoso de Simpson.

7. Pienso que si se habla de la andanza de una mujer siendo tan sexy que hace caer anheles, es codigo para ciertas propiedades anatómicas.) El "antes de todo" cubre lo de decidir entre el trono y ella.

---

El premio Nobel (consonante si no me equivoco)

> Edu por
> su amor
> abdicó:
> prefieró
> Simpsona
> chulona.
> "Lo haré:
> andaré,
> porqué no
> obtuvó
> un nave.
> La clave
> del trono:
> ¿Rey o no?
> Contempló:
> eligó
> su fiero
> trasero."
> Población:
> "¡Decepción!"
> A B. Stan
> no gustan
> Edu y
> la yanqui.
> George: "Y hoy,
> el rey soy"
> '36/
> 12/10

(El año era 1936.)

Comment: No había comprendido lo de consonante. Quito mis matemáticas artísticas.

Comment: ¿Quién es **él**?

Comment: He añadido la respuesta a esta pregunta. No ve manera hacerlo sin robar el Edu de @walen: Eduardo es más de tres sílabas.

Comment: Y además es bastante Yodisto-macarronico. Vencer el golf intento yo.

Comment: No veo las rimas, no entiendo que has hecho

Comment: Para divertirme continuó lo que pensaba ser rimante y que no lo fue. No intento conseguir el bonus.

Comment: ¿y entonces porque pones 134 / 107?

Comment: La version larga vale 134 y la corta (bajo) vale 107.

Comment: ah vale. Qu tienes dos, no me había fijado en la segunda versión ;)

Comment: Y no soy capaz de contar.

Comment: @blonfu perdóname mi formatting. Lo he hecho un poquito más legible.

Comment: Saludos @Mörkö... tu respuesta debería ser un poema, distribuido en 14 versos, lo que le quita validez a la última respuesta que entregas

Comment: Para usar las palabras bien eligidas de @Charlie, a la porra la rima., ¿No era posible dar una respuesta en prosa?

Comment: "12.10" no es "año, mes", sino más bien "mes, día" (10 de diciembre).

Comment: @Charlie bien visto

Comment: en español, el Duque de York era Jorge

Answer (score 2):

### 153 (bonus consonante) = 138 caracteres

Hay que intentar algo mientras queda tiempo:

> Por amor
>   Eduardo cesó
>   ¡Qué revés
>   gobierno inglés!
>   diciembre 10
>   de Jorge es la vez
>   Baldwin protesta.
>   "cruzo el mar con esta
>   remando
>   o andando
>   mi reino doy
>   por Simpson hoy
>   si camina
>   se me empina"

Comment: el RU creo que es abreviatura... tendrías que modificarla

Comment: Es verdad, que no valen abreviaturas. A ver si puedo arreglarlo